# Sending objects through bluetooth on android, how do I serialise object and send?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've read a ton of SO threads on this and im still confused. I need to send a ship object, for a battleships game. I've made the ship class implement serializable, but I can't seem to send the object. I've basically just used code I've found online and incorparated it into my code for connectedThread (same as android dev site). Code is below. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong, any help is greatly appreciated. I get errors when i run the code, which seem to be coming from the objectinputstream side

```
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private ObjectOutput out = null;
    byte[] yourBytes = new byte[1024];

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connectedthread started");
        // mHandler.obtainMessage(TEST).sendToTarget();
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        yourBytes = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {

            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created");
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;

    }

    public void run() {

        Log.i(TAG, "Begin mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    Log.i(TAG, "reaaaad msg");
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(SetUpGame.MESSAGE_READ2, bytes,
                            -1, buffer).sendToTarget();

                Log.i(TAG, "READ OBJECT");
                    // ........................................THIS IS CODE THAT HAS ERRORS-----------
                    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourBytes);
                    ObjectInput in = null;
                    try {
                        in = new ObjectInputStream(mmInStream);
                        Ship yourObject = (Ship) in.readObject();
                        //Log.i("Object received maybe", yourObject.toString());
                        if(yourObject!=null)
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(SetUpGame.MESSAGE_READ_OBJ, -1, -1, yourObject).sendToTarget();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        bis.close();
                        in.close();
                    }

 // -----------------------------------IF I DELETE THE ABOVE CODE IT WORKS FOR STRINGS PERFECTLY------
                }

            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnectd");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {

        try {

            mmOutStream.write(buffer);
            Log.i(TAG, "writeeee msg");
            mHandler.obtainMessage(SetUpGame.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write");
        }
    }

    public void writeObj(Ship ship) {
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput out = null;
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(mmOutStream);
            out.writeObject(ship);
            yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
            out.close();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close of connect socket failed");
        }
    }

}
```

and logcat:

```
03-21 02:41:41.594: E/AndroidRuntime(12529): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 02:41:41.594: E/AndroidRuntime(12529):    at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:58)
03-21 02:41:41.594: E/AndroidRuntime(12529):    at com.example.battleships.v2.ChatService$ConnectedThread.run(ChatService.java:280)
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529): Activity com.example.battleships.v2.MainScreen has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.battleships.v2.MainScreen$2@40521320 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.example.battleships.v2.MainScreen has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.battleships.v2.MainScreen$2@40521320 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:799)
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:575)
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:865)
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:852)
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:846)
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529):    at com.example.battleships.v2.MainScreen.setUpUI(MainScreen.java:167)
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529):    at com.example.battleships.v2.MainScreen.onCreate(MainScreen.java:160)
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
03-21 02:41:41.875: E/ActivityThread(12529):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
```

Comment: Please update your post to include a description of what errors you are getting.

Comment: I added some errors I was getting and I made clear what section gives me the errors in the code. If I remove that code it works for strings. Also, I apologize for the format of logcat errors. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have overridden the class variable "out" by redeclaring it inside the method writeObj(). Remove "ObjectOutput out = null;" from writeObj().

Also you seem a bit uncertain as to which stream you are writing to as you keep resetting the class variable "bos".

You are probably getting a NullPointerException because you are trying to use a variable that isn't in scope in the way that you think it is.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll play around with the code a little later, but I'm so confused with sending objects through bluetooth. The worst thing about it is I can't find any working examples for similar projects or any resources that explain it like I'm 5 lol. Thank you for your time tho!